# Statistical method to prove inverse relationship between class size and student achievement

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, exploratory-data-analysis

A hypothesis states that there is an inverse relationship between class size and student achievement.

With data records about class sizes and grades of its students at a certain school, we would like to find out whether the hypothesis holds.

Which statistical methods could be chosen for that?

Comment: I think that a [simple linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) will be sufficient for your purpose. Please see [this document](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/309/Book/chapter9.pdf) for more details.

Comment: @Aleksandr What is the basis for supposing the relationship ought to be linear, or even approximately so? This seems like a situation where one should adopt a strong initial suspicion of *nonlinearity* and work first to establish the nature of the relationship before going through any kind of fitting procedure. But perhaps you have studied similar datasets and discovered, though experience, that the relationships do look linear?

Comment: I don't think you should set out to *prove* a negative relationship, you should set out to find out the truth. And, as @whuber says, I believe the literature shows that classes which are too small don't do well, and classes which are too large don't do well.

Comment: @Jeremy That situation is even worse than nonlinear!--and therefore your comment is quite useful. Rather than presupposing the relationship is inverse (which presumes *monotonicity*), perhaps one should be prepared to see a complicated relationship such as a "U-shaped" one.

Comment: @whuber: I understand your point. I don't have experience with similar data sets. However, my idea was to use an _alternative approach_ for this case, generating and testing hypotheses in the increasing level of _complexity_. In other words, to start with an assumption that the relationship is _linear_ and work through more complex models, if each subsequent hypothesis, based on a simpler one, is found to be not true (rejected).

Comment: @Aleksandr That is an excellent point and well stated. It considerably modifies the message sent in your initial comment. You seem now to be saying that linear regression might *not* be "sufficient," but it would be a good place to start. I would not quarrel with such advice, but personally would advocate EDA (perhaps on a subset of the data, to allow subsequent formal testing on the held-out data) before moving to using *any* kind of model.

Comment: @whuber: You're right, indeed! I absolutely agree with starting with EDA before moving any further. Appreciate the kind words as well, especially coming from you.

Comment: What do you know about the classes and how they were formed? For example, perhaps your analyses should omit remedial and honors classes, both of which might tend to be relatively small in size. For the other classes, why would you expect much variation in size?  Would not the administration try to equalize class size?  Your research question might better be approached with an experimental design than a correlational design.